# How to format inner html text of an element without changing format of subelements? (Selector)

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors, styles

I have an html with the following structure:

```html
<p>
  This is some test inside the p tag
  <div class="some-class">
    <div class="sub-div-class">
      <i title="title test" data-toggle="tooltip" class="some-icon-class" data-original-title="Title test" style="color: rgb(25, 118, 210);">
        <svg width="21" height="18" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" aria-hidden="true" class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill">
          <path d="m10.79 12.912-1.614-1.615a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l-2.06-2.06C.938 6.278 0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5a7.029 7.029 0 0 0 2.79-.588zM5.21 3.088A7.028 7.028 0 0 1 8 2.5c5 0 8 5.5 8 5.5s-.939 1.721-2.641 3.238l-2.062-2.062a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474L5.21 3.089z">
          </path> 
          <path d="M5.525 7.646a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829l-2.83-2.829zm4.95.708-2.829-2.83a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829zm3.171 6-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z">   
          </path>
        </svg>
      </i>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
```

I'm trying to change the "This is some test inside the p tag" opacity without affecting the icon opacity. Any ideas?

I've checked on selector documentation but I have not seen anything that can help.

Important Note, This html is generated from VueJS components so they are in fact rendered as they are seen, I'm looking for a selector That only takes the raw text from a p tag to style it but don't selects other elements inside the p tag.

Comment: Since a `<div>` is not a valid child of a `<p>` element, your browser almost certainly creates the `<div>` as a sibling element to the `<p>` (Firefox 102 and Chrome 103, Ubuntu 22.04 both do), so `p.style.opacity = 0.5;` *shouldn't* cause any problems and doesn't in the named browsers: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gp30ketz/), other browsers may of course behave differently.

Comment: Ok, probably I should have been more descriptive: This html I copied is generated from VueJS components, so the divs in fact are inside the p tag, so this comment doesn't help in this case

Comment: Are they? To an extent browsers will “rescue” broken html, but will often allow you (or your code) to insert broken markup, have you verified that the `<div>` elements are within the `<p>` elements?

Comment: I have, and they are indeed inside the p tag.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense it's possible because they are different nodes.

```js
var text = "hello world";
document.querySelector("p").firstChild.data = text;
```

```html
<p>
  This is some test inside the p tag
  <div class="some-class">
    <div class="sub-div-class">
      <i title="title test" data-toggle="tooltip" class="some-icon-class" data-original-title="Title test" style="color: rgb(25, 118, 210);">
        <svg width="21" height="18" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" aria-hidden="true" class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill">
          <path d="m10.79 12.912-1.614-1.615a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l-2.06-2.06C.938 6.278 0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5a7.029 7.029 0 0 0 2.79-.588zM5.21 3.088A7.028 7.028 0 0 1 8 2.5c5 0 8 5.5 8 5.5s-.939 1.721-2.641 3.238l-2.062-2.062a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474L5.21 3.089z">
          </path> 
          <path d="M5.525 7.646a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829l-2.83-2.829zm4.95.708-2.829-2.83a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829zm3.171 6-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z">   
          </path>
        </svg>
      </i>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
```